# Search for a Column in all the schema

Tags: db2

Is there any query which can list out all the tables from all the schemas in which specified field is present in DB2 database?
I tried searching for the solutions but I am not able to find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below Query.

```
select TBNAME
from sysibm.syscolumns
where NAME = '<column name>'
```

Comment: On DB2 for i you would use schema QSYS2 vs. SYSIBM

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I tried using QSYS2 but it failed with "Unidentified name" error. SYSIBM schema is working fine for me.

Comment: Ok, you did not specify which flavor of DB2 you are speaking of. There are three platform specific codebases which are slightly different: `DB2 for LUW`, `DB2 for z/OS`, and `DB2 for i`. `QSYS2` is used by `DB2 for i`.